# Package dependency issue: linux-server

Tags: 12.04, dependencies

I am using 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 and logged in as root.

When I try to run:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-48-generic but it is not installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.49.59) but 3.2.0.48.58 is installed
```

If I try to run:

```
apt-get -f install
```

I get a similar error.

I have tried manually downloading and installing the package but I get the same error:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-server_3.2.0.49.59_amd64.deb
dpkg -i linux-server_3.2.0.49.59_*.deb

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.49.59); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.48.58.
```

I also get a similar error if I try to remove the linux-server package:

```
apt-get remove linux-server

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-48-generic but it is not going to be installed
```

It seems every solution to other posts where people have run into the same problem that I have tried give me a similar error.

Update:
I found a solution. I had to remove linux-server, linux-image-server, and linux-headers-server at the same time in one command.

Comment: Ok I got it. I had to remove linux-server, linux-headers-server, and linux-image-server all in once command.

Comment: "Update: I found a solution. [...]" Please post answers as answers. We don't add answers to questions here. It's how this site works. And yes, it's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't update some packages because they depend on some new packages which are new, or rely on new kernel, etc. And while your system is LTS (long term supported) it's very important to be sure about updates, this can be a reason to impossibility to simply update - that means you need to upgrade

this may help you

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Hi Rodislav. It is always better to elaborate on your answer. For example, you should mention what this command does.